# Comparing the lenght of each element in a list to a certain number in Python

Tags: python, list

I have only started to learn coding, and for me using lists are still a bit fuzzy. I have a sample exercise which is really easy, but I somehow haven't figured it out yet.

I have given a sample list consisting of random things

```
things = ["car", "base", "space", "dog", "pan"]
```

And I have to have a new variable equaling 0, eg.`counter = 0`

I have to make a program which checks if the length of each element is 3, if it is I have to add 1 to counter. Then I have to print the counter.

Thanks in advance for all your help!!

Comment: So, it sounds like you want to count the number of strings in the list that are of length 3. Please include the code that you wrote to try and solve this?

Comment: List comprehension have higher performance than the functions

Comment: echoing jarmod, searching for an online tutorial about computing the lengths of strings is often a good place to start.  You may also find a need to learn about lists and loops to assist with your task.  Here is a reasonable starting point quickly obtained via google search:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-length-of-a-string-in-python-4-ways/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in range(len(things)):
    if len(things[i])==3:
        count +=1
    else:
        print('len is > 3')

print(count)
```

- range(len(things)) measures the length of the list and runs the loop that many times
- things[i] will give you each element in the list since i = 0,1,2,3....n

Comment: @ak16005 if the solution work for you, can you consider giving an upvote (clicking on the arrow above 0) for my answer

Answer (score 0):

Theres a simple way and a magicky pythonic way, simple first:

```py
ls = ["yeet", "ba", "bop", "boop"]
count = 0
for w in ls:
  if len(w) == 3:
    count+=1

print(count)
```

now for the magic way:

```py
print(len([w for w in ls if len(w) == 3]))
```

The [ (here) ] part is called a list comprehension and it supports mapping and filtering values.

Comment: Could replace `len([w for w in ...])` with `sum(1 for w in ...)` for memory effiency.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do it:

```
counter = sum([1 for x in things if len(x) == 3])
```

Another way:

```
counter = 0
for item in things:
    if len(item) == 3:
        counter += 1
```

Comment: You can use a generator expression instead to avoid creating a list `sum(1 for x in things if len(x) == 3)`